# Fancybox 3: how to show the small close button for modal iframe?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

I am using Fancybox 3 to display a modal iframe. Here is my code to initialize Fancybox:

```
    modal: true,
    smallBtn: true,
    iframe: {
        css: {
            width : '900px',
            height: '600px'
        },
        preload: false 
    }
```

If I remove `modal: true`, I am able to see the small button. However the small button does not show up if I set `modal: true`.

Comment: Hi, I've opened up an issue on Github, as I do seem to be experiencing the same thing https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1719

Answer (score 1):

From the docs about `modal` option:

```
// Shortcut to make content "modal" - disable keyboard navigtion, hide buttons, etc
modal : false
```

So, if you set it to `true`, there is no button displayed as expected.

Some demo demonstrating small close button - 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaVyYV?editors=1010